# Will a Canadian refugee travel document allow visa-free entry to Georgia?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, georgia-country, refugees

I have a Canadian refugee travel document and I also have valid work permit. I traveled to Turkey and I didn't know that I needed a visa to enter Turkey.

Now I changed the plan and I want to travel to Tbilisi (Georgia). Do I need to get a visa to enter Georgia?

Comment: You can check on the [Georgian Ministry of Foreign Affairs website](https://geoconsul.gov.ge/en/entering-georgia-visa)

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica It doesn’t seem all that complicated to me

Comment: In general, you need visas for refugee travel documents.

Answer (score 6):

From traveldoc.aero

> Visa is required for passengers holding travel documents issued to
> stateless persons, refugees or aliens.

However, you can apply for eVisa here - https://www.evisa.gov.ge/GeoVisa/

Edit:

I tried to apply for eVisa with details you provided. It shows this.

You are exempt from visa!

> Holders of valid visa or residence permit of the country you have
> selected are exempted from visa requirements. You can enter Georgia
> without a visa for 90 days in any 180-day period. Please, note that
> you must present relevant valid visa or residence permit along with
> your travel document/passport at the moment of crossing Georgian
> border. Detailed information on visa free travel is available on the
> following website: [www.geoconsul.gov.ge](http://www.geoconsul.gov.ge).

You can try filling the application and it will tell you.